# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException error occur in vs2010 c#

Tags: c#

when i execute vs2005 project on vs2010 so the break point appear and the message appear[image]

on that line 
  chartPage.Export(@"C:\excel_chart_export.jpg", "JPG", misValue);
give me the solution so i can use without any error in vs2010?

Comment: change the target framework to some lower version (3.5/2.5) and then test.

Comment: Did you try to run Visual Studio elevated?

Comment: this project is running on 2005 but not on 2010....

Answer (score 0):

There's simply something wrong with the project itself, as it has a dependency on a COM object.

Grab a crash dump and you will see the stack trace.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/03/20/debugging-a-net-crash-with-rules-in-debug-diag.aspx